# IFTTT - Grocery List Automation

Tags: if-this-then-that

Basically I'm trying to create a grocery list by sending a list of items to my Gmail. I'll create a rule that "stars" the Gmail based on the Subject Line "Groceries" then I want to take the body of the email (the list of groceries) and add it to Reminders list or Evernote list or somewhere that I can updated it.

My issues is that I cannot figure out how to isolate the body of Gmail.

Answer (score 4):

If the if trigger is Gmail being starred, then there is a `{{bodyplain}}` ingredient. You can add this to an Evernote note for your *Do*.